# How to search for the nearest non nan value in 2d xarray dataset

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling, atmospheric-circulation, python

I have a 2d xarray dataset and I am having several nan values in the dataset. These nan values need to be filled with the nearest non-nan values in the 2d array. How do I do this?

I am trying to make my data consistent with the grid_spec file that the earth system model reads. And there are inconsistencies on what the land points are in the forcing data and grid_spec file leading to the blowing up of model.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: @ManmeetSIngh  I think this would get better tracking on SO rather than here.

Comment: Look up Numpy .isnan(<your element or array>).

Comment: Or try using a masked array (mask where nan)

Comment: How do you define distance?

Comment: @Spencer I have solved this, and the distance is defined as going around the missing value point round and round, For eg if the missing grid point is the middle 1, then we need to search 6,7,8,2,6,5,4,0 in cycle 1, still if we are not able to find the non-nan we will move to the second cycle

12345
56789
90123
34567
89012

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would exclude the NaN values and then perform gridding on the resulting irregularly spaced data.

There are already the tools to perform this in Python and using the library SciPy

https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data.html

But please document exactly what step you are doing and why. Excluding data is always ... interpreting the data.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do this by the following functions

```
def fill_mismatch(ds_grid_spec, ds_data):
    ds_data_o = ds_data.copy()
    count = 0.0
    for i in range(ds_grid_spec.shape[0]):
        for j in range(ds_grid_spec.shape[1]):
            if ds_grid_spec[i,j].values > 0.0 and (not ds_data[i,j] > 0.0):
                count = count + 1.0
                fill_miss2d(ds_data_o, i, j)
            if ds_grid_spec[i,j].values == 0.0 and (not ds_data[i,j].values == 0.0):
                count = count + 1.0
                ds_data_o[i,j] = 0.0
    return ds_data_o

def fill_miss2d(ds, lat_i, lon_j):
# fist cycle
    cycle = 1

    while True:
        bl_i, bl_j = lat_i - cycle, lon_j - cycle
        tr_i, tr_j = lat_i + cycle, lon_j + cycle
        # Bottom left i
        if bl_i < 0:
            bl_i = 0
        # Bottom left j
        if bl_j < 0:
            bl_j = 0
        # Top right i
        if tr_i > ds.lat.shape[0]-1:
            tr_i = ds.lat.shape[0]-1
        # Top right j
        if tr_j > ds.lon.shape[0]-1:
            tr_j = ds.lon.shape[0]-1

        lats_i = np.arange(bl_i,tr_i)
        lons_j = np.arange(bl_j,tr_j)
        for lats_i_idx in lats_i:
            for lons_j_idx in lons_j:
                if ds[lats_i_idx, lons_j_idx]>0.0:
                    ds[lat_i, lon_j] = ds[lats_i_idx, lons_j_idx]
                    return
        cycle = cycle + 1
```

The grid_spec (which is the most commonly used grid exchange file for Modular Ocean Model MOM) had a variable AREA_LND and the file soiltype.nc had a variable soiltype. Both these variables had 0.0 at the grid points classified as ocean. Hence we dont need to use fill_miss2d where a mismatch occurs and ocean is encountered in grid_spec, but land is there in soiltype. Rather we directly fill the soiltype grid point with 0.0

The complete notebook can be found at https://github.com/manmeet3591/python_class/blob/master/xarray_tutorial/grid_soiltype.ipynb